# Need to convert to Mon DD, YYYY HH:MM from YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert `Decimal(17,9)` datatype to `Timestamp(6)`.

Example, I am having `Decimal(17,9)` value as `20150619.154519` and I need to convert it to `timestamp` like `Jun 19, 2015 15:45`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time and cast.)

Comment: Also, never store date/timestamp as varchar. Use date/timestamp data types!!!

Comment: Wondered what the guy who stored a date in a decimal column was thinking. Obfuscation?

Comment: Database is oracle 11G

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange format.  First convert it to a string, then to a date:

```
select to_date(to_char(col, '99999999.999999'), 'YYYYMMDD.HHMISS')
```

Actually, this would probably work without the `to_char()` part, but it seems safer to do the conversion explicitly.